# Detect pattern in incoming byte stream

Tags: arduino

I would like to detect a certain byte pattern in an incoming byte stream at the UART. I am using Arduino. Currently, the code detects a single `\r` character. On this character is detected, the byte stream before this character gets stored into a buffer. This is easy. This is my code;

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {
  // send data only when you receive data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0 ) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
    if (incomingByte != '\r') {
      buffer_incoming_data[index_buffer]=incomingByte;
      index_buffer++;
    } else {
      index_buffer = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my problem. Instead of a single character `\r`, I would like to detect a byte pattern that looks like this `0xAA 0xBB 0xCC`. When this byte pattern is detected, the byte stream before byte pattern gets stored into a buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you invoke loop() method inside real loop operator. I can suggest next way:

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data


int pattern [] = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC};
int patternIndex = 0;
int patternSize = sizeof(pattern)/sizeof(pattern[0]);

void loop() {

    // send data only when you receive data:
    if (Serial.available() > 0 ) {
        // read the incoming byte:
        incomingByte = Serial.read();

        if(pattern[patternIndex] != incomingByte){
            // if we found begin of pattern but didn't reach the end of it       
            if(patternIndex>0){
                for(int i=0; i<=patternIndex-1; i++){
                    buffer_incoming_data[index_buffer]=pattern[i];
                    index_buffer++;
                }
            }
            patternIndex = 0;
        }

        if(pattern[patternIndex] == incomingByte){
            patternIndex++;
        }else{
            buffer_incoming_data[index_buffer]=incomingByte;
            index_buffer++;
        }       

        //if we reached the end of pattern
        if(patternIndex==patternSize){
            //do something with buffer
            patternIndex = 0;
            index_buffer = 0;                
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I didn't check `index_buffer` for *"index out of range"* exception, but you should. Hope I helped you.